# -rf means in SFDX CLI command?

Tags: salesforcedx, cli

**rm -rf mdapipackage**
in this command what **-rf** means?
When I am using in my Visual Studio its showed below error.

Please help me with this.

Remove-Item : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'rf'.
At line:1 char:4
+ rm -rf mdapipackage
+    ~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Remove-Item], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RemoveItemCommand

Answer (score 2):

The command expects to run in a Unix-like shell (e.g. bash, zsh, etc), but you're using PowerShell. The `rm` command in PowerShell works differently.

In a shell that supports this syntax, it means "--recursive --force", and is meant to delete all matching sub-directories and files, and ignoring permissions errors that can be ignored (such as read-only).

Change your shell to a bash (e.g. git's bash shell, GitHub's desktop integration includes a shell, etc), or you'll have to use those commands "manually" (e.g. right-click and Delete the folder).

In VS Code, in the Terminal Pane, there's a dropdown near the top-right side that will allow you to switch to a Bash shell, if one is installed on your computer.

Answer (score 0):

`rm` is not specifically a SFDX CLI command and its used to remove a directory. There is not `rf` parameter on this command. May be it was meant to be like this

```
rm -r -f mdapipackage
```

You could do the following command to see the list of available parameter

```
rm --help
```

Comment: For PowerShell, the help would be `rm -?`. The command itself would be used as `rm -R -F <path>`